# Unable to create a DX11 render target view

Tags: directx, texture2d, rendertarget

I'm trying to get started with DirectX 11 game programming, but for some reason I'm simply unable to create a render target view with ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView().

(BTW, I use VS for Desktop 2013, and the highest feature level my GPU supports is 11_0. I'm running Windows 8.1.)

Here's the code I think is relevant:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC backBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&backBufferDesc, sizeof(backBufferDesc));
    backBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    backBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    backBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    backBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
    backBufferDesc.Height = nHeight;
    backBufferDesc.Width = nWidth;
    backBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    backBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    backBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    backBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    backBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

    ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferTexture;
    result = d3dDevice_ -> CreateTexture2D(&backBufferDesc, 0, &backBufferTexture);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Failed to create the back buffer texture!", "DirectX Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    result = swapChain_->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferTexture);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Failed to get the swap chain back buffer!", "DirectX Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC rtvDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&rtvDesc, sizeof(rtvDesc));
    rtvDesc.Format = backBufferDesc.Format;

    result = d3dDevice_->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferTexture, &rtvDesc, &backBufferTarget_);
    if (backBufferTexture)
        backBufferTexture->Release();
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Failed to create the render target view!", "DirectX Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Debug Device would give you a human readable error.

Based on my reading of the code you haven't filled out the ViewDimension field of rtvDesc.

Comment: It turned out I didn't even need the rtvDesc. It was a parameter of swapChainDesc that wasn't set correctly. Thanks though.